# Checkbox stays checked even though prop is false

Tags: reactjs

I'm checking the url for some value then determining if the checkbox should be in a checked state or not.. this is only decorative, the checkbox is not clickable.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={inCurrentFilters({ key: bucket.key, dotField, currentFilters })}
/>
{inCurrentFilters({ key: bucket.key, dotField, currentFilters }) ? 'true' : 'false'}
```

When `inCurrentFilters` returns `true` the checkbox is checked and it says `true` next to it. Then when it returns `false` the checkbox remains checked and the value says `false`. What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own solution is the simplest way to resolve it. The checkbox you render is an input element, so by default users can click it. Since you are not using it as an input, `pointer-events: none` does the trick.

From a User Experience perspective, it may be better to make the checkbox `disabled`, or use 2 icons that look differently.

By showing default checkboxes, you are essentially telling users that they can click the checkbox, which they should not.

Comment: We used to use an icon instead of a checkbox but we switched it to a checkbox input element because apparently some people turn css off and still want to view the site, and our font awesome icons wouldn't appear.

Comment: I see. `disabled` will also do the trick without css, but that is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

So.. interestingly enough, it *was* clickable and I was overriding the function state by clicking on it. I added `pointerEvents: none`. This fixes the issue, but is there a better way?